# Dynamic if else for both source and replacement columns in dplyr across

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I have this table:

```r
df <- data.frame(value_2022 = c(1, NA, 3), 
               volume_2022 = c(NA, 2, 3), 
               value_2022_replacement = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5),
               volume_2022_replacement = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5))
df
#>   value_2022 volume_2022 value_2022_replacement volume_2022_replacement
#> 1          1          NA                    1.5                     0.5
#> 2         NA           2                    2.5                     1.5
#> 3          3           3                    3.5                     2.5
```

I would like to programmatically replace the NA values of each 2022 column with their corresponding _replacement columns through `across`, my code looks like the following:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(across(matches("^v.+2022$"), \(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 
                                                  {replacewithcorresponding "_replacement" variable}, 
                                                  x)))
```

I am wondering whether there's any way to substitute `{replacewithcorresponding "_replacement" variable}` by something that allows me to do this for an unlimited number of columns that match the {same name}_2022_replacement pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate((across(matches("\\d{4}$"), ~ coalesce(.x,
    pick(str_c(cur_column(), '_replacement'))[[1]]))))
```

-output

```
 value_2022 volume_2022 value_2022_replacement volume_2022_replacement
1        1.0         0.5                    1.5                     0.5
2        2.5         2.0                    2.5                     1.5
3        3.0         3.0                    3.5                     2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the {dplyover} package for this. Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer and the package is not on CRAN.

The easy way is `across2`, it requires the columns to be in the according order:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover)


df %>% 
  mutate(across2(ends_with("_2022"), # below .x
                 ends_with("_2022_replacement"), # below .y
                 ~ ifelse(is.na(.x), .y, .x),
                 .names = "{xcol}"
                 )
         )
#>   value_2022 volume_2022 value_2022_replacement volume_2022_replacement
#> 1        1.0         0.5                    1.5                     0.5
#> 2        2.5         2.0                    2.5                     1.5
#> 3        3.0         3.0                    3.5                     2.5
```

The safer but a bit more verbose option is `dplyover::over()`. Here we first extract the variable stems with `cut_names()` and then use `.("")` to constract and evaluate the string variable names inside the function in `.fns`:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(over(cut_names("_replacement"), # extracts c("value_2022","volume_2022")
                 ~ ifelse(is.na(.("{.x}")),
                          .("{.x}_replacement"),
                          .("{.x}")),
                 .names = "{x}"
                 )
         )
#>   value_2022 volume_2022 value_2022_replacement volume_2022_replacement
#> 1        1.0         0.5                    1.5                     0.5
#> 2        2.5         2.0                    2.5                     1.5
#> 3        3.0         3.0                    3.5                     2.5
```

Data from OP

```r
df <- data.frame(value_2022 = c(1, NA, 3), 
                 volume_2022 = c(NA, 2, 3), 
                 value_2022_replacement = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5),
                 volume_2022_replacement = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dplyr solution that uses the `cur_data()` and `cur_column()` functions. The spacing of my `mutate` statement isn't normally how I'd format it, but I think this makes it a little easier to read for demonstration purposes.

```
df <- data.frame(value_2022 = c(1, NA, 3), 
                 volume_2022 = c(NA, 2, 3), 
                 value_2022_replacement = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5),
                 volume_2022_replacement = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5))

df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      matches("^v.+2022$"),
      \(x) ifelse(is.na(x), cur_data()[[paste(cur_column(), 'replacement', sep = '_')]], x)
    )
  )

  value_2022 volume_2022 value_2022_replacement volume_2022_replacement
1        1.0         0.5                    1.5                     0.5
2        2.5         2.0                    2.5                     1.5
3        3.0         3.0                    3.5                     2.5
```

Comment: I do like this answer, although since dplyr 1.1.0 `cur_data()` is deprecated. Any idea on how to use the `ifelse` statement without resorting to cur_data?

Comment: Okay, I solved it through `ifelse(is.na(x), pick(everything())[[paste(cur_column(), 'replacement', sep = '_')]], x)`